# Translation to normal forms – Skolemization

Tags: logic

I got to negation normal form and I understand the process of translation to normal forms, but for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out how to do the skolemization part. The nnf is ∃x(q(f(x),g(x))∧∀y(¬p(y,x)∧¬(q(x,c))). Do I substitude all x by s(x)? thanks for any help

Comment: No; replace $x$ with a constant $c$, because there is no universal quantifier preceeding $\exists x$.

Comment: Do I use the same constant c I already have or a new constant?